# Suddenly URLs with "table/"

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, url, category, sh404sef

I'm running a simple site based on Joomla. The SEF URLs are defined by SH404SEF and look like `https://[domain]/[category]/[sub category]/[article title alias].html`.
 In some cases there is a 1-to-1 relationship between category and article but in some cases one category has several articles.

Suddenly I have URLs requesting `https://[domain]/table/[category]/[sub category]/`. Not only do these new URLs in some cases create 404s, they also view my articles in the wrong way and when there is not a 1-to-1 relationship between category and article the link adds several articles on one page.

The correct non-SEF URL ends with `&view=article` and the new, incorrect non-SEF URL ends with `&view=category`.

I have no `table/` in:

- my correct URLs
- any internal link
- the articles' html code
- menu items
- my sitemap.xml.

I've discussed this with the few extension providers that I am using and none of them see their extension as doing this new request.

Is there any way to find out what is making these requests?

I cannot make a redirect for these URLs because all of them correspond to several articles (instead of just one).

Can you see any risk with making a rewrite rule that puts a 410 on all URLs that starts with `table/`?

Comment: Take a look here https://weeblr.com/helpdesk/sh404sef/1122-table-in-url

Comment: KlintWeb, thanks for your response! 

Yes, I've read that link. Disabling table names in SH404SEF would get rid of the "table" URLs but not my problem since these list views would still be requested, shown and indexed as I've understood it.

Due to different reasons I would like to get rid of the category lists, that is not how I want my site to be viewed.